# Bootstrap 4 component not formatting in Angular 4 test app

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I am building a simple test app in Angular 4, and have installed boostrap 4 for angular (per instructions here `https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started`).

I have imported boostrap into the root module and into my simple navbar menu component which uses bootstrap classes (code taken from a working plnkr example).

My app shows the menu but only as a list, not formatting for bootstrap css/js.  I can post code but I don't think that's the problem as I followed the linked above exactly.

Is this symptom enough for someone to offer advice?  If not I'll start posting code snippets.

---

UPDATE:

I added the link to boostrap's CSS and now the list items are no longer visible (just the 'brand' and little grey box) so the CSS helped.  The proper rending of a navbar seems like a seperate question so I have split this off.

The answer was to add the link to the Bootstrap 4 CSS, even though the ng-bootstrap website does NOT say this is required.

Comment: Are the Bootstrap files loading when you look at Chrome Dev Tools? It sounds like they aren't.

Comment: Yes my sample page appears in the browser (created by ng new project), and the 'ng serve' window shows it all compiled fine.  Just the menu appears as nested lists instead of a menu formatted by bootstrap 4.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood.  If I look at the NETWORK tab of developer tools I can check which files are loading - but what file exactly should I be looking for?  (I'm not sure how Boostrap 4 for Angular is broken up into files).

Comment: The CSS and JS files will say Bootstrap in them. If they aren't being loaded there, you won't get the goodness.

Comment: only .js files load, but I suspect that webpack has bundled everything together so you don't actually see any css files loading.  with Angular4+NgBootstrap4 it's a different world

Comment: I use ngx-bootstrap and it has nav-bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you linking the Bootstrap css files into your project? Typically you would include these at the root of your project (in a css directory) and then link them into your `index.html` file like this:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css">
```

This assumes a deployment structure like this:

```
  index.html
  /css/
```

You can download the Bootstrap code here:

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com

Then copy the css directory to the root of your project directory.

If you want to use the Bootstrap code hosted from the Bootstrap CDN server (Content Delivery Network) instead of maintaining your own local copies, link to them here:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Don't link to the stylesheets used by the Bootstrap public pages as these links may change in the future, unexpectedly breaking your site.

Comment: Are you sure that's necessary with the Bootstrap for Angular 4 project?  Their instructions (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) and downloaded code don't say to do any of that

Comment: Yes - you need the CSS. If you're using ng-bootstrap then you don't need the CSS, you can just npm install the ng-bootstrap project and it implements all the JavaScript as proper Angular directives, but you need the CSS.

Comment: I'm using ng-bootstrap installed as above, so then I should be ok without making reference to the css file.  But, I'm starting to think NAVBAR is not included in ng-bootstrap (but that seems like such a massive oversight that it can't be right)

Comment: I'm using ng-bootstrap. Trust me, you need the CSS.

Comment: Bootstrap is a combination of CSS styles (resets, standard styles for headings, buttons, nav bar elements, grids etc.), and JavaScript elements (drop downs, carousels, tabs and accordions etc.). ng-bootstrap implements the JavaScript functionality as Angular directives/components so that you can easily use them in Angular projects in an Angular way, but the CSS styles aren't Angular specific, and the JavaScript components, both standard Bootstrap versions and the ng-bootstrap versions depend on the Bootstrap CSS files for styling. You need to link in the CSS.

Comment: ok I've added the CSS and now the list items are no longer visible, but it doesn't format as a NAVBAR.  Could it be that navbar is not available in ng-bootstrap?  You may wish to update your answer since those 3 links don't apply to ng-bootrap, but adding a link to <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> worked,

Comment: Can you add the HTML for your component to the question so I can see the structure of your nav? I use nav extensively in my Angular projects with ng-bootstrap without any trouble. Also I would suggest serving your own CSS files - if my links didn't work then your project structure is likely different. If you want to use the hosted styles, use the CDN links, not the ones from the Bootstrap public page as they may change and break your app in the future.

Comment: I accepted  your answer above, as the list items visible appears to be completely related to the missing CSS.  (I suggest updating your answer for ng-bootstrap specific however).  As for proper rending of the navbar I opened as a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45552429/navbar-not-rendering-in-browser-using-ng-bootstrap-angular-4