# Navbar doesnt work in an bootstrap: 4.0.0-beta.2

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, bootstrap-4

I have installed latest version of `Bootstrap`:

```
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
"bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.2",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"jquery": "^3.2.1",
"popper.js": "^1.12.9",
```

And I implemented a `navbar`:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light" *ngIf="!isLogged">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active" routerLinkActive="active current">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/sign-up"><span class="">Sign Up</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active" routerLinkActive="active current">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/login"><span class="">Login</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Which should transform into `button` when come to mobile size. Actually it does but that `button` doesn't react for any clicks. Why? Does anyone have any clue?  I did not add any scripts to `angular.cli`.

UPDATE:
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZWB2.png)

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
```

Comment: Have you checked your Console for errors?

Comment: No errors actually

Comment: _I did not add any scripts to angular.cli_. Are you saying you haven't provided any of the JS dependencies because the **collapse** functionality won't work with them. This question may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45552429/navbar-not-rendering-in-browser-using-ng-bootstrap-angular-4

Comment: I wrote _I did not add any scripts to angular.cli._ because I tried to add: `scripts": [
        "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js/jquery.slim.min.js",
        "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js"
      ],` but t throws errors ex.:
`ERROR in multi script-loader!./src/~/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js/jquery.slim.min.js script-loader!./src/~/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve`

Comment: Correct. You'd have to have JS to actually have access to the dropdown module.

Comment: Can you update your question with a screenshot of your project folder? Might be a path problem. And did you install jquery, popperjs? Edit: you have an extra jquery.slim.min.js in your script import.

Comment: I updated. Yes I installed popperjs and jquery

Comment: If you’re implementing **ng-bootstrap** you don’t need any of the standard Bootstrap JS dependencies. You should look into the [Docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you should have in your .angular-cli.json

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
    "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ],
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
  ]
```